# Flask WTForms not showing the data

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am new to python and flask and trying to understand "wtforms" but so far didn't find any tutorials that actually explains the complete functionality. Like in some places data is set in the "GET" request like

> form.country = DBModel.country

some use it like

> form.country.data = DBModel.country

other use it like

> form.country.query = DBModel.country

The other thing I don't understand is "wtforms" functionality in "POST" request.

> Where exactly data is extracted from the request?

I cannot see any data extraction from request in any example. They simply define the instance of "wtform" and starts adding the data to DB.

Comment: Can you provide server side code? That helps to answer this question as perfect?

Comment: Hey Waseem! Your question is almost there but it would be best if you showed an example of what your problem is. A good start would be to write a small WTForms application(if you are getting started just write the one right out of the documentation) if you run into a problem and can't find an existing answer feel free to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You are new in Python and Flask read [this](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) blog :) It contains series of articles how to start and develop the flask project. It can be very useful.

About problems with wtforms try to find something useful in flask [snippets](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/).

In wtforms.Form you have properties [**data**](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms.html#wtforms.form.BaseForm.data) - it is a dict containing the data for each field. If You want to fill form with data from model there is [**populate_obj()**](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms.html#wtforms.form.Form.populate_obj) method.